# Не удается подключиться к базе данных Postgres в Linux

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, c++, linux

При выполнении выдает No connection, при этом сеть между компьютером и виртуальной машиной (на которой выполняется ./readwritepaths) установлена (ip основного компьютера, на котором установлена база 192.168.143.92). Программа pgAdmin 3 запущена с запущенным сервером 192.168.143.92(localhost:5432) во время выполнения программы readwritepaths.

```
conn = PQconnectdb("hostaddr=192.168.143.92 port=5432 connect_timeout=5 dbname=NexentaSearch user=DKOI password=21111991");
if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {
    puts("No connection");
    exit(0);
}
```

Подскажите, как сделать программу работоспособной?

Comment: @ivan31, Вы мне начинаете надоедать. Пишите, пожалуйста, свой вопрос с человеческим форматированием. Иначе глазки приходится ломать.

Comment: Я не знаю как это сделать?

Comment: Ну, так изучите в конце-концов правила пользования ХэшКодом. Встроенный редактор все умеет.

Comment: а права на удаленное подключение по сети к базе данных есть?

Comment: @vv2, а как проверить наличие этих прав?

Answer (score 3):

[[@ivan31](/users/4705/ivan31)](/users/4705/ivan31) Конфигурация PostgreSQL по умолчанию не разрешает входящие подключения с внешних компьютеров. Это означает, что никакие внешние приложения не могут получить доступ к вашей базе данных. И то что возвратила программа "Connection to database failed: timeout expired" лишь подтверждает факт того, что необходимо произвести соответствующие настройки, чтобы разрешить удаленный доступ к базе данных.

Смотри раздел "Настройка удалённого доступа к PostgreSQL"
[Как настроить PostgreSQL и интегрировать ее с PHP и Apache?](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL_%28%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%29)

Answer (score 2):

[[@ivan31](/users/4705/ivan31)](/users/4705/ivan31), к сожалению ни разу не работал с Postgress из С++.

Первый же нагугленный пример показывает, что аргументы соединения в параметре PQconnectdb заключены в апострофы.

```
psql = PQconnectdb("hostaddr = '127.0.0.1' port = '' dbname = 'fwaggle' user = 'fwaggle' password = 'password' connect_timeout = '10'");
```

Может быть дело в этом ?

P.S. Уважаемые отвечающие/оценивающие!  Ну, не знает человек тему, хочет разобраться, **зачем минусовать?**

Comment: @avp, спасибо за дельное замечание, но к сожалению это не решило проблему.

Comment: Попробуйте PQerrorMessage

     fprintf(stderr, "Connection to database failed: %s",PQerrorMessage(conn));

Comment: Выдало Connection to database failed: timeout expired

Comment: @avp По описанию апострофы требуются, если значение содержит пробелы или является пустым

Comment: @ivan31, "*timeout expired*" - интересно. В [документации](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/libpq-connect.html)

    connect_timeout

    Maximum wait for connection, in seconds (write as a decimal integer string). Zero or not specified means wait indefinitely. It is not recommended to use a timeout of less than 2 seconds.

Попробуйте явно задать в PQconnectdb что-нибудь большое.

Comment: Так у него 5 секунд (connect_timeout=5). Можно попробовать выполнить эту же программу прямо на компутере (реальном), где postgresql... Если там работает, то смотреть, почему пакеты (вероятнее всего) не проходят между виртуальным и реальным компами.